# Leaking LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks

I encountered an issue with a leak on the in android's native heap in my app. The leak seems to come from LinkedBlockingQueue that is just keep growing without being cleaned up.

If you look at the look below, the native heap has a total of 478M and it keeps growing (it started from 20M and it keeps growing by around 250k every few seconds). The JVM heap is working correctly and stays at a the same levels around 100M. My app uses its own network code but even with it turned off and the app just "sits" there it still have this leak.

I have identified that the LinkedBlockingQueues are point to an com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool instance (the same one). I don't use okhttp anywhere in my code. I do use firebase with config, database and storage support. But with the exception of the config that has attached listener the other services are not while I'm testing.

[image: Console Log]

The snapshot below shows my java heap dump. The LinkedBlockingQueue has 6029 instances and almost 300M of retained memory. This number grows with the native heap increase so I'm assuming they are related.

[image: hpref classes]

The snapshot below shows one of the LinkedBlockingQueue$Node instances where the item is the connection pool. They all look the same and pointing to the same item.

[image: hpref instance]

I never encountered a memory leak like that and not sure what is the reason for it. I would appreciate if any of you have any thoughts of what it could be or if you had an issue like that before.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This had nothing to do with my app or firebase. It seems that Android Studio with ADB Integration may have been the cause. 
When I disable the integration and used Android Device Monitor for memory and getting the logs. The native heap doesn't grow and stays at around the same levels.